# Como utilizar bien el id de la session_start a para utilizarlo en el UPDATE de una base de datos

Tags: php, html, pdo, session

Esto me esta llevando unos cuantos días/semanas en solucionar, en un principio me pareció fácil, pero veo que no, explico:
A partir de una base de usuarios session_start empieza una session por el usuario que ha hecho Login. Todo bien pero aquí llega a la hora de el UPDATE, el usuario tiene la opción de actualizar su información almacenada, placeholders social1, social2 , aboutt.
Cada usuario tiene id único.
El problema llega al no saber yo como entrelazar el id que creo que me da la session_start con el archivo de actualizar.
Que yo creo que por eso me da este error, `Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => )`que por lo que se eso significa que el codigo funciona pero no hace la funcionalidad deseada. No actualizando el registro de dicho usuario.
Por eso creo que utilizar el id dado por `session_start`sería la clave que haría funcionar el código bien y insertarlo donde pertenece.

**Formulario para introducir los datos que remplazaran a los otros**
Aquí  `<input type='hidden' name='id'  >` es lo único que se me ha ocurrido, pero está mal.

```html
<?php
 session_start();
 include 'pd.cambio.conn.php';
 
 ?>
 <html>
 <head>
<title>Actualizar Libro</title>
<h1 class="username"><?php echo $_SESSION['name']; ?></h1>
     
 
 </head>
 <body>
 
     <form action='actualizardos.php' method='post'>
     <table>
         <tr>
         <input type='hidden' name='id'  >
             <td>Autor:</td>
             <td><input type='text' name='social1' pattern=[A-Z\sa-z]{3,20} ></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>Fecha Edición:</td>
             <td><input type='text' name='social2' pattern=[A-Z\sa-z]{3,20}></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
         <td>Fecha Edición:</td>
             <td><input type='text' name='aboutt' pattern=[A-Z\sa-z]{3,20}></td>

              
</tr>

</table>
<input type='submit' name='actualizar' >

 </form>
 </body>
 </html>


?>
```

**Archivo php que hace todo el trabajo del `UPDATE`**

```html
<?php
session_start();
require 'pd.cambio.conn.php';   
if(isset($_POST['actualizar'])){
    $id=trim($_POST['id']);
    $social1=trim($_POST['social1']);
    $social2=trim($_POST['social2']);
    $aboutt=trim($_POST['aboutt']);
    $data = [
        'social1' => $social1,
        'social2' => $social2,
        'aboutt' => $aboutt,
        'id' => $id,
    ];
    $sql = "UPDATE users SET social1=:social1, social2=:social2, aboutt=:aboutt WHERE id=:id";
    $stmt= $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($data);

    if($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
    {
    $count = $sqli -> rowCount();
    echo "<div class='content alert alert-primary' > 
    
    Gracias: $count registro ha sido actualizado  </div>";
    }
    else{
        echo "<div class='content alert alert-danger'> No se pudo actulizar el registro  </div>";
    
    print_r($stmt->errorInfo()); 
    }
    

       }
   


?>
```

Aquí creo que es donde se tienen que hacer los cambios.

**conexión a la base de datos**

```html
<?php
// Connection variables
$dbhost = "localhost";     // localhost or IP
$dbuser = "root";         // database username
$dbpass = "";            // database password
$dbname = "xxxx";    // database name

$options = [
    \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    \PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => \PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    \PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
];
$dsn = "mysql:localhost=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname";
try {
     $pdo = new \PDO($dsn, $dbuser, $dbpass, $options);
} catch (\PDOException $e) {
     throw new \PDOException($e->getMessage(), (int)$e->getCode());
}


?>
```

Repito, aquí creo que el problema existe al no vincular el `id` del `UPDATE` con el de `session_start` pero creo que también lo puede tener el archivo que hace la actualización.
Lo que me sale ahora cuando lo hago es: No se pudo actualizar el registro
Array ( [0] => 00000 [1](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/375114/como-se-puede-a%C3%B1adir-el-id-de-phpmyadmin-del-usuario-de-la-sesi%C3%B3n-abierta-en-el) => [2] => )
Muchas gracias de antemano, un crack el que me ayude!

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**
EL código actualizado, ahora con el resultado: `0 records UPDATED successfully` que lo entiendo perfectamente ya que no se declara a que id de phpmyadmin tiene que ir los datos actualizados . El id es un numero único que ya fue dado por el autoIncrement en phpmyadmin. (El formulario es el mismo, no hay cambios en él)

```html
<?php
session_start();
include 'pd.cambio.conn.php';
try{    
$conn = new PDO("mysql:localhost=$dbhost; phplogin=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);
$conn->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");      // Sets encoding UTF-8
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  
 $pdo = "UPDATE users  
 SET social1 = :social1,
     social2 = :social2,
     aboutt = :aboutt
     
WHERE id = :id";               



 $statement = $conn->prepare($pdo);
 $statement->bindParam(":social1", $social1);
 $statement->bindParam(":social2", $social2);
 $statement->bindParam(":aboutt", $aboutt);
 $count = $statement->execute();

  
 echo $statement->rowCount() . " records UPDATED successfully";
}catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
   
   $conn = null;        // Disconnect
?>
```

EL código de `UPDATE`se asemeja bastante al dado por W3schools.
La pregunta sobre el utilizar el id de phpmyadmin con sesión abierta para `update` ha sido formulada [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/375114/como-se-puede-a%C3%B1adir-el-id-de-phpmyadmin-del-usuario-de-la-sesi%C3%B3n-abierta-en-el) ya que no quiero sobrecargar esta pregunta con mucha información para futuras visualizaciones buscando este determinado problema.

Comment: Cuando te refieres a las variables estas son las que empiezan con: $id=trim($_POST['id']);
    $social1=trim($_POST['social1']);
    $social2=trim($_POST['social2']);
    $aboutt=trim($_POST['aboutt']);                                                                                    I en la declaración preparada en que parte del código sería? Gracias ajsoler!

Comment: Vale! He escuchado sobre el bind_param, pero no tengo claro donde seria la edición. Sería en $data? o debajo de    $sql = "UPDATE users SET social1=:social1, social2=:social2, aboutt=:aboutt WHERE id=:id";     I si fuera ahí, entonces $data tendría que ser eliminada?

Comment: @ajsoler ¿Entonces no hay que hacer ni un vínculo entre la session_start y el id del formulario?

Comment: Bueno, yo pensaba que la session se podía utilizar para indicar a que usuario es el que hace las actualizaciones, ya que esto hay que imaginarlo de tal manera. Usuario  Juan hace login, se dirige a perfil para actualizar sus datos, todo esto pasa en el lado del usuario , entonces las variables de $social1, $social2 $aboutt de momento no se ve que tengan error, (pude que lo tengan) y el id del usuario que esta (online cambiando sus datos) yo pensaba que solo se podía usar la session abierta. Pero voy a probar ajsoler.

Comment: @xelfury entiendo tu ejemplo de Juan, pero lo que no entiendo es si por predeterminado session_start te da el id de la fila que Juan ocupa en phpmyadmin, para la actualización de sus datos. No entiendo la referencia a mostrar manualmente los errores de la conexión en la base de datos, donde esto sucede en mi código?

Comment: @xelfury Vale, entiendo perfectamente, entonces estuve probando lo que me dijiste sobre las variables que no están atadas a la declaración, he intentado arreglarlo, pero amigo, no se que pasa pero el me sigue dando error, (poniendo lo del bindParam.

Comment: @xelfury Mi última pregunta es, que pasa aquí con el id, no acabo de entender si se tiene como pasar como una variable mas, como por ejemplo social1, ho hay que hacer-le algo diferente, yo creo que si porque eso no lo tiene que poner el usuario, eso ya lo tiene i ademas es un AUTO_INCREMENT que va dado, entonces xelfury o alguien que este leyendo  este post, ustedes saben que se tiene que hacer? Gracias( Perdonen las molestias he tenido que ponerlo en dos comentarios, si no no cabía)

Comment: @xelfury He hecho un cambio, se puede ver en ACTUALIZACIÓN, para el final. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: No entiendo por qué en varios comentarios se sugiere usar código basado en `mysqli` para resolver el problema, cuando es evidente que estás usando PDO, que es una API totalmente distinta a `mysqli`. El mensaje de error que estás teniendo es porque en los `bindParam` no estás pasando parámetro para `:id`, si observas la consulta preparada del `UPDATE` indicas en ella un marcador para `:id`, pero luego no pasas ese parámetro.

Comment: @A. Cedano, si te entiendo cuando dices lo de pasar el parámetro, pero por falta de práctica y maestría en este ámbito por parte mía no llego a la conclusión de si el parámetro id es diferente o igual que los demás, yo lo que pienso es que el parámetro id tendría que tener algo relacionado con la session, no? Ya que la session activa con un id único dado por phpmyadmin, no por session_id (esto es importante ya que se puede confundir) es él que marca donde hay que hacer el update, señor puede ver que estoy un poco perdido, o mas bien dicho falto de información, usted que piensa?

Comment: @A.Cedano SIn ninguna duda voy a probar de pasar el parámetro id, conjuntamente  con los otros, comento dentro de un rato. Gracias

Comment: Por el momento olvida lo de la sesión o no sesión, quizá ni siquiera haga falta usar sesiones si estás trabajando con bases de datos, pero ese es otro asunto. Vamos a centrarnos en esto: `UPDATE users  SET social1 = :social1, social2 = :social2, aboutt = :aboutt WHERE id = :id`, estamos ante una consulta preparada que usas marcadores de `:nombre`, o sea, se usan los marcadores precedidos por dos puntos. En esa consulta, debes pasar con `bindParam` un valor por cada marcador, también para `:id` porque así lo has indicado en la consulta. Otra cosa es si se deba usar `id` o no...

Comment: ... ese es otro asunto que debes decidir en la lógica de tu programa. Si el `UPDATE` debe actualizar basándose en un `id`  concreto debes pasar sí o sí un parámetro para el `id` lo tomes de donde lo tomes. El motivo del error aquí es ese, no otro. Una vez resuelto eso podrás decidir entonces de dónde tomar el `id`.

Comment: Tu sentencia preparada falla porque no ligas valores con la clave :id. No hace falta usar `bindParam()` cuando se usan parámetros con nombre. Puedes usar un array de pares `clave => valor` así: `$params = [":social1" => $social1, ":social2" => $social2, ":aboutt" => $aboutt, ':id' => $id];` y ejecutar `$statement->execute($params);` directamente. Pero pasando el id en $id. Ese id puedes enviarlo al formulario en `<input type='hidden' name='id' value="<?=$uid ?>" >"` dónde $uid es el id del registro de usuario que deseas actualizar

Comment: @quevedo Pero entonces $uid por que sería compuesta? Tendría que venir del login como estuvimos hablando A.Cedano y yo? Compruebe la otra pregunta que va enlazada para eso del login, como se haría. Gracias señor quevedo, su foto de perfil es un cuadro muy interesante y que da mucho de que hablar, me gusta, la persistencia de la memoria, de Dalí.

Comment: Hola. $uid lo recoges del id del usuario cuando se loggea y lo pasas en el valor del campo oculto. Cuando este postea la edición, lo lees de $_Post['id'] y haces validación antes de ejecutar el query de actualización de datos (no sea que te suplanten al usuario)

Answer (score -2):

Lo que pasa es que estás llevando un campo vacío en el "input id hidden" trata de hacer lo siguiente:

Donde imprimes `$_SESSION['name'];` asimilo que lo traes de la tabla `user` al hacer login.. bueno trata de hacer lo siguiente:

`$id= $_SESSION['id'];` // Así como traes el `name` del user podrás traer su ID y esa variable imprimela en el value del campo id hidden de tu formulario para que se pueda enviar al controller para hacer el proceso del UPDATE :)

saludos, espero te sea de ayuda mi comentario.

Comment: Gracias Jairo! Entiendo el campo vacío,  pero el id conjuntamente con otros datos y el nombre van juntos en la conexión de la session. I al imprimir el nombre se muestra en la pantalla, pero creo que el id en esta situación tiene que estar oculto a ojos del usuario. Pero he probado lo que me he has dicho, en diferentes sitios, después del '<?php' i de la 'session_start' dandome como error undefined index. He probado también en el campo type, donde dice lo de hidden, y en el campo name. Dando el mismo error, undefined index.