# Como se puede añadir el id de phpmyadmin del usuario de la sesión abierta en el UPDATE para actualizar los datos del user en pdo

Tags: php, html, base-de-datos, pdo, session

esta pregunta parte del problema planteado en [1]: [Como utilizar bien el id de la session_start a para utilizarlo en el UPDATE de una base de datos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/374279/como-utilizar-bien-el-id-de-la-session-start-a-para-utilizarlo-en-el-update-de-u)

El proceso es el siguiente, la base de datos que tengo en `phpmyadmin` cada vez que se crea un usuario se creo un fila, con el contenido que el inserta, pero en el proceso se crea un id `(AUTO_INCREMENT)`, la razón por el id es por si el usuario quiere hacer algún cambio a sus datos almacenados, se tendrán que diferenciar uno de los otros gracias al id.
Entonces el problema llega a la hora del `UPDATE`. Los datos que son necesarios para el `update` son dados por un formulario que el mismo usuario rellena, menos el id, que eso no se puede cambiar ya que marca donde hay que hacer los cambios. La sesión del usuario es abierta mediante `session_start()`.

**Formulario**

```html
<?php
 session_start();
 
 
 ?>
 <html>
 <head>
<title>Actualizar Libro</title>
<h1 class="username"><?php echo $_SESSION['Name']; ?></h1>

     
 
 </head>
 <body>
 
     <form action='actualizardos.php' method='post'>
     <table>
         <tr>
         
         
             <td>Autor:</td>
             <td><input type='text' name='social1' pattern=[A-Z\sa-z]{3,20} ></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>Fecha Edición:</td>
             <td><input type='text' name='social2' pattern=[A-Z\sa-z]{3,20}></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
         <td>Fecha Edición:</td>
             <td><input type='text' name='aboutt' pattern=[A-Z\sa-z]{3,20}></td>

              
</tr>

</table>
<input type='submit' name='actualizar' >

 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

**Archivo con el `pdo` que hace la actualización**

```html
<?php
session_start();
$dbhost = "localhost";     // localhost or IP
$dbuser = "root";         // database username
$dbpass = "";            // database password
$dbname = "phplogin";    // database name



try{    
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost; dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);
  $conn->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");      // Sets encoding UTF-8
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  $conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false );
 $pdo = "UPDATE users  
 SET social1 = :social1,
     social2 = :social2,
     aboutt = :aboutt
     
WHERE id= :id";               



 $statement = $conn->prepare($pdo);
 $statement->bindParam(":social1", $social1);
 $statement->bindParam(":social2", $social2);
 $statement->bindParam(":aboutt", $aboutt);
 $statement->bindParam(":id", $id);
 $count = $statement->execute();

  
 echo $statement->rowCount() . " records UPDATED successfully";
}catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
   
   $conn = null;        // Disconnect
?>
```

Entonces ahora el error mostrado actualmente es:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE 'id'= ?'
```

Yo creo que el error es dado porque el código no tiene idea de en que `id` hay que insertar los datos que vienen del formulario. Hi ha ahí desconozco y es el origen de mi pregunta si hay que vincular o algo la `session_start`(que muestra que sesión esta abierta) y el `id` que hay en `phpmyadmin`.
Creo que esta pregunta tiene valor en cuanto ha sesiones y pdo en el entorno del usuario, ya que esta pregunta es formulada de maneras diferentes en bastantes sitios. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Tu error parece ser por que después de esto `aboutt = :aboutt` pones una coma que indica esperas declarar otro valor a actualizar, entonces prueba quitárselo

Comment: Además quítale las comillas a id

Comment: @BetaM Vale arregle eso que me dijiste y una variable que la tenía mal escrita, ahora lo interesante es que me devuelve 0 records UPDATED sucessfully, que esto ya es un avance en torno a errores, pero no actualiza nada. Yo creo que el código no tiene idea de donde tiene que hacer la actualización (en que id) no se como eso de el id se puede declarar de alguna forma. Que piensas?

Comment: Leí tu anterior pregunta y también esta y no logro entender el por qué de este `UPDATE` ¿? ¿En qué momento / contexto ocurre? Se supone que en un primer momento ocurrió un `INSERT` donde se creó el usuario ¿no?  Pero ¿y este `UPDATE` para qué es, qué sentido tiene, cuándo ocurre y por qué ocurre? Me parece que más que nada tienes un error de comprensión/organización lógica de tu programa. Respondiendo a lo que te acabo de preguntar quizá el asunto se aclare un poco más.

Comment: @A.Cedano Si, la lógica viene así, para poner un ejemplo el señor López se encuentra en mi página web, el señor López se registra, cuando se registra el formulario le pide datos. (Por ejemplo le pide su nombre de usuario en twiter, que se inserta en social1, le pide el usario que tiene en facebook, se inserta en social2, le pide  una descripción de que le gusta hacer, se inserta en aboutt,) (aquí también le pide el email y una contraseña i un nombre).    EL señor López, ahora registrado ahora se convierte en el usuario López (aquí es donde ocurre el INSERT respondiendo a una de tus preguntas)

Comment: Bien, eso se entendió. Ya Mr. López existe pero, ¿qué hay del `UPDATE`? ¿Por qué se requiere actualizar datos de Mr. López? ¿En qué contexto ocurre esa actualización? Debes explicar eso para que podamos ayudarte.

Comment: @A.Cedano Entonces el usario Lopez, ya registrado y con sus datos en la base de datos, los datos que él ha puesto más el id único que se le ha dado (en phpmyadmin por ejemplo el 1) que le identifica a él. El usuario López procede hacer login, en el login se valida que sea él y se abre una session.

Comment: Ahora el usuario López habre su perfil, en la pagina web y ve que ha hecho un error, por ejemplo ha puesto que le gustan los perros pero ahora le gustan los gatos. Usuario López entonces abre la página en la página web de EditarPerfil. Mediante un formulario pone los datos que quiere que se actualicen y le da a actualizar. Hi ha ahí es donde el UPDATE tiene su sentido.  Perdona estaba escribiendo pero me ha surgido un problema. Lo siento @A.Cedano

Comment: Entendido. Entonces en ese contexto en el cual Mr. López ingresó al sistema tú habrás guardado su `id` (en una variable de sesión, en un elemento html o donde quieras) ¿no? Entonces para hacer el `UPDATE` necesitas el id sí o sí, pues de lo contrario actualizarías todos los registros, no solo el de Mr. López. Entonces, no entiendo cuál es el problema en sí. Debes usar el id, en el `WHERE` del `UPDATE` sacándolo de dónde lo hayas guardado cuando Mr. López entró al sistema.

Comment: @A.Cedano Vale, el id fue guardado en phpmyadmin, pero el problema reside ahí, nos se que código hay que poner para sacar el id para que el UPDATE sepa donde tiene que ir los datos que quieren ser actualizados. Ya que al ingresar por primera vez ese usuario, ese id fue dado de manera aleatoria, y fue dado por phpmyadmin con AUTO_INCREMENT no fue dado por mi, ahí es donde reside el problema. Una vez leyendo encontré que con esto <?php echo $_SESSION['Name']; ?>  se puede mostrar el nombre del usuario de la sesión activa, probé con el id pero no funcionó, gracias A.Cedano, que me recomienda?

Comment: No te líes de nuevo. En uno de los comentarios dices que el usuario entra en el sistema, revisa los datos y ve que ha cometido un error: puso que le gustan los perros pero resulta que no, que son los gatos. Pues bien, vayamos a ese punto: cuando el usuario ingresó en ese contexto, ¿de qué modo ingresó? Supongo que hiciste una verificación mediante una consulta `SELECT` ¿no? Pues en ese contexto debes traer el `id` y guardarlo en alguna parte para poder usarlo cuando sea necesario actualizar algo. Si estás usando sesiones, puedes guardar el `id` en algo como `$_SESSION['id']` por ejemplo.

Comment: @A.Cedano Vale, en mi código si que se hace un select como tu has mencionado, pero en vez de el id se utiliza el email. I así es $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT Email, Password, Name, social1, aboutt FROM users WHERE Email = '$email'");  y la variable $email se desenvolupa así,  $email = $_POST['email'];  que el POST viene del placeholder del formulario de login. Hay alguna forma de coger y guardar el email  para poder utilizarlo en actualización? Coger-lo del select o algo, estoy un poco perdido ahí. Gracias señor Cedano.

Comment: Puedes usar el `Email` si éste es único, pero lo más seguro será siempre el `id`, por tanto, como ya dije, puedes incluir el `id` en el `SELECT`, guardarlo en un elemento, como haces con los otros datos, y recuperarlo con algo como `$_POST['id']` a condición de que envíes un campo con el dato como haces con `email`. ¿Entiendes lo que quiero decir o no?

Comment: @A.Cedano He hecho que el email sea único en cada cuenta (me mirado un tutorial) parece que va bien, me tengo que estudiar aún el código para entenderlo. ¿Lo de incluir el id? ¿Seria substituyendo el email o se pasa y así ya lo tenemos? Señor Cedano yo pensaba que $_POST[''] se ponía cuando se obtenía un dato del formulario, en caso de $_POST['id'] este dato no sería dado por el formulario (pude que me equivoque), y si tengo que enviar el campo con el dato a mi archivo UPDATE pero me sale mal, he probado con el email, que tenia ya alguna variable pero nada, undefined index todo el tiempo.

Comment: @A.Cedano Me gustaría preguntarle ahora que sabe el origen y mi problema en si, si sabe de algún sitio oficial donde pueda yo nutrirme de información sobre mi problema, pero agradezco mucho lo que esta haciendo, gracias a gente como usted hace unos días decidí responder preguntas en stackoverflow en español, para aportar. Voy a estar trabajando estos días a ver si puedo crear el campo ese con el dato de el id o el email del usuario que ha iniciado session para poder hacer el UPDATE. Puede que me haga otra pregunta en el foro con este problema mas complejo, para no cargar esta pregunta de más.

Comment: Si decides cambiar el identificador tendrás que crear la columna `id` en la tabla y definirla como `auto_increment`, así cada vez que se inserte un registro esa columna aumentará en `1` y será un valor único para cada fila. Con respecto al POST, los valores que encuentres en él son los que pases al mandar los datos al servidor, si no los encuentra es porque no se están pasando. En el caso de `form` tendría que haber algo así más o menos `<input name="id" value="1">` para poder encontrar el valor con `$_POST["id"]`...

Comment: En programación web generalmente intervienen varios lenguajes, tecnologías, framweorks, etc. Para aprender cada cosa recomiendo que te dirijas a los sitios oficiales de cada cosa (Manual de PHP, Manual de Referencia de MySQL, MDN para Javascript, etc). Y cuando haya dudas, para eso está Stackoverflow, para que preguntes lo que necesites, tratando de ser lo más claro posible.

Comment: @A.Cedano Estuve dandole al coco unos días, y he encontrado $row['Id'], estoy trabajando con eso a ver que, si puedo sacar el id del usuario logeado, aquí le dejo el link si quiere echar un vistazo. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/376379/como-guardar-el-id-del-usuario-logueado-para-utilizarlo-despu%c3%a9s-en-un-update